# Refresh parent lightning component detail page from embedded lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, refresh

I have a lightning component in a custom lightning record detail page. I want to force refresh on the parent page when the lightning component is loaded. i.e.

1. I open a record.
2. Record detail page loads- this is the custom lightning record detail page.
3. Custom lightning component embedded at the bottom of the page loads.
4. In the custom lightning embedded component, I have the following piece of code. (within helper)

   ```
   updateAssignedTo : function(component, event, helper) {
   var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
   console.log('Record Id&&&&&&****'+recordId);
   var action = component.get("c.updateAssignedTo");

   action.setParams({
       accountRequestId : recordId,
   });

   action.setCallback(this, function(response){
       var state = response.getState();
       if (state === "SUCCESS") {
         **$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();**
       }else if (state === "ERROR") {

       }
   });
   $A.enqueueAction(action);
   },
   ```

var action = component.get("c.updateAssignedTo"); is successfully called.

I am trying the refresh the parent page by the following piece of code.

```
$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
```

However, it is not happening.

Is this a feasible way to do it?

Comment: If the parent component is also custom (your code) - you need to listen to the `force:refreshView` event - add to your markup: `<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.doInit}" />`

Answer (score 1):

Try using lightning data service, and then call a controller method in the "recordUpdated" attribute. Something like this-

**Component**

```
<aura:attribute name="oppRecord" type="Opportunity" />
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />

<force:recordData aura:id="dataService"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      targetFields="{!v.oppRecord}"
                      fields="Id,Name,StageName,..(whatever you want, or use the layout)"
                      layoutType="FULL"
                      mode="EDIT"
                      recordUpdated="{!c.handleRecordUpdated}"/>
```

**Javascript Controller**

```
handleRecordUpdated : function(component, event, helper) {
    // refresh the page with the record updates
    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
},
```